# Sharepoint Same list content but different group by

Tags: list, sharepoint

I want to create multiple list pages using the same List data/content but just applying different Group By filters.

Is there a way to achieve this the easiest way with limited coding?

Comment: Two q: a) Do these groups have different rights on the list? b) How do filter the list by group?

Comment: a) no all users can see any lists b) by group by filters, I meant each list will be Group By different columns

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you want, you don't need any coding at all. 
Create a number of pages with the list WebPart, that you need and set different Views for them, where you have configured the Group By rule individualy for each View.

Comment: However does this work if each list will contain the same items content?

Comment: 1) Is it that lists will have the same data only initially or do you plan that the data will change throughout the use and the data will be different for these lists?
2) Are all these pages to be located in the same web?